# changing KVM domain xml file on the fly

Tags: xml, dns, kvm, diskimage

I would like to change the xml file of a currently running domain (change the diskimage) on the fly. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. But any change to the XML file requires a reboot of the VM for the changes to take place. Hope it helped.